# wish to replicate a symbol seen in an equation

Tags: equations, symbols, wolfram-mathematica

i have a image and i want to write equation from the image
how i can write **g** in equation ?

> at first i write `g_{vix}\left ( s \right )` but **g** is not like **g** on
>   the image

[image: my image]

Comment: [Check here first](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character), but that looks like a `\mathcal{g}_{\mathrm{vis}} (S)`. I’m not sure which `\mathcal` font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope the below may helps you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{G}_{\mathrm{vis}} (S)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you will add `\usepackage{newtxtext)` is the same of the picture. Very good.

Comment: Thanks. Shall I rephrase?

Comment: No. It is only a suggestion if you wanted use Times New Roman fonts instead of the classic computern modern (CM) for the text. It is perfect.